# Parsing XML from URLwith javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have an xml contained in a url. The xml contains information that I would like to access using javascript. In particular, I would like to access the record ID numbers. Any help would be appreciated. The XML is contained [here](https://homesquare.quickbase.com/db/bij3xqndm?act=API_DoQuery&ticket=8_egp8sukxb_b2b92t_dmpt_a_dthwmsbdfjfzg5bfpsm3mbxnmaiddctskjbxw2t7zbmc8xambis3bkm&apptoken=5pvyk4bw5xdu2bct798ycgcibte&query=%7B%27190%27.EX.%27%27%7D&clist=3.143&options=num-4).

The code I tried is as follows. However, it tells me that the url is an invalid argument.

```
function importTable() {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://homesquare.quickbase.com/db/bij3xqndm?act=API_DoQuery&ticket=8_egp8sukxb_b2b92t_dmpt_a_dthwmsbdfjfzg5bfpsm3mbxnmaiddctskjbxw2t7zbmc8xambis3bkm&apptoken=5pvyk4bw5xdu2bct798ycgcibte&query={%27190%27.EX.%27%27}&clist=3.143&options=num-4");
    var doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: What is the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to URL encode the curly braces in your URL. { = %7B and } = %7D

For the XML traversal itself, I recommend the tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_traverse.asp

The syntax is reasonably straightforward unless you have oddly named XML containers.

Comment: Thank you. So now that I have stored the xml in response, how do I access the information stored in it? Specifically, I'm looking for the record ID numbers in each property record.

Comment: Edited my answer with additional info.